# Count the number of arrangements of the letters in PHYSICS.

Tags: combinatorics

I thought it would be $7!$, but my book gives $7c2 * 5!$ as the answer. I don't understand why, considering we have $8!$ ways of arranging the letters in PHYSICAL.

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand now. You have 2 S's in PHYSICS, so you need to choose a combination of them first from the two letters and then do a permutation of the remaining 5 letters.

Comment: Done, that is all!

Comment: When using the combination, we don't care about the order of the S's, so we only want a subset of them?

Comment: Yes, because the $S$ are all the same, so there is no "order" between the same elements.  The only question is where do the two $S$s lie in terms of the new word i.e. you have to *choose* two positions  out of $7$ for the $S$s, and then permute the rest five as usual.

Comment: When we choose the two positions for the S's, it doesn't matter where they are? So one S can be at the beginning, one S can be at the end, and anywhere in between? So in another arrangement, the first S can be in any of the 7 available positions, and the second S can be in any of the 6 remaining positions?

Comment: Yes, but there's no difference between the first and the second $S$, so it does not matter which one goes in the position chosen first, and which one goes in the position chosen second. That is why we are "choosing" the positions of the $S$ and not "permuting" the $S$s, because they look the same regardless of how you permute them! So that is why we do $^7C_2$ and not $^7P_2$